# trouble with table of clickable buttons that needs to prevent double clicks on focused button while keeping the following ones clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of clickable buttons and use a flag variable to prevent a double click on the focused button. The flag works and I get the intended alert saying 'you have already clicked that'. The problem is that the following button will be treated as if it has also already been clicked and I'll get the alert again. I don't want this.

```
  var _clickFlag = true;

    /* #Volunteers is a table. Each row on the table has a button that says "accept",
 I pass the function the 'event' object which I use to get specific data from that table 
row and send it to a database*/

     $('#Volunteers').on('click','#accept', function(event){

       //if clickFlag = true then the button hasn't been clicked yet. 

        if(_clickFlag){

           //here I send some stuff to a database. I don't want to send it twice for the same 
           //row, which is why I need to prevent a double click

           //set clickFlag to false to prevent double submission

                _clickFlag = false;



    }else{

    //alert if the button has been clicked once already

        alert("already accepted");
    }


    });
```

Comment: there should be a mistake in your code, you are probably using the same id more than one for your buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double click is a separate event, I assume you are talking about clicking the button more than once, if that is the case your variable that you defined is in the outer context is shared to all button, what you need is to define a variable inside the function and tie it to the button itself, try the below:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JFtw/

```
 $('#Volunteers').on('click','.accept', function(event){

   //if clickFlag = true then the button hasn't been clicked yet. 

    if(typeof this._clickFlag != 'undefined' && this._clickFlag){

       //alert if the button has been clicked once already
       alert("already accepted");

}else{

    //here I send some stuff to a database. I don't want to send it twice for the same 
    //row, which is why I need to prevent a double click
    alert('_clickFlag: '+this._clickFlag + ' First time processing!');
    this._clickFlag = true; 

}


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
$( "#Volunteers").unbind( "click" );
```

This will just make the button unclickable.

Comment: And most people prefer  .off() rather than the .unbind function now days. Its up to you what you want to use.

Comment: If I use unbind it will make all the buttons useless. I only want the clicked on disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations I like to use attributes, ex:

```
 $('some-button-here).attr('data-active','false') // This sets the attribute for that button
```

You can then check this attribute everytime one of the buttons is clicked.